# Why does my makefile not do what I want - clash between implicit and explicit rules?

Tags: makefile

The website that I am building from sources consists of mainly two groups of files. Firstly, a set of HTML files that include PHP processing instructions that I process with PHP **at build time** as part of producing localized markup files. Said another way, a HTML file from source directory is processed with PHP which pipes output to another HTML file in the build directory with the same name.

The processing of said HTML files involves a set of PHP files of its own. These files carry the actual localization texts that substitute placeholders in the source HTML files. These PHP files in turn are generated from corresponding XML files. This because we have chosen XML as the original carrier for the localization texts, as this project is part of a larger one that is rather heterogenous with regards to technology used, and so we went with XML, also to aid ourselves in rapid translation.

Secondly and lastly, I have a second group of files that we can call "static" assets, which simply need to be copied verbatim froms source to the build directory.

I am struggling to write a concise makefile for use by GNU make that expresses the dependencies correctly. At best I accomplish half while `make` seems to play tricks on me that confuse me.

A brief legend for the makefile below, you can prolly skip this if you really pick things up fast:

- The process that converts localization data from XML format to the code that PHP can `include` is invoked with the `xml_to_php_res`. The XML files are in current (source) directory and match `*.res.xml`.
- Invoking PHP to `include` the localization files and process HTML files is abstracted in the `process_html` script
- `DESTDIR` make variable is used to indicate the prefix of the build directory. Since it's a prefix, it usually ends with a `/`, when defined. For obvious reasons, it *cannot* match source directory.
- Source directory is assumed to be the current directory
- The localization PHP files that are produced from XML files match `$(DESTDIR)resources/*.php`. I don't discard them after use because 1) it's good to cache them and 2) They can be used at runtime, if deemed required. I guess these are what `make` calls "intermediate" prerequisites?

The makefile:

```
php_pp_def_files := $(patsubst ./%.res.xml,$(DESTDIR)resources/%.php,$(shell find -name \*.res.xml))

$(DESTDIR)resources/%.php: %.res.xml
    ./xml_to_php_res $< > $@

$(DESTDIR)%.html: %.html $(php_pp_def_files) # Each built HTML file depends on corresponding source HTML file and all PHP localization definition files
    ./process_html $< > $@

$(DESTDIR)%: %
    $(INSTALL_DATA) -D $< $@
```

The last rule appears to interfere with my intentions. It seems that's the way `make` is designed - if some prerequisites for the second rule don't exist, it simply skips it and considers third rule instead. That's not what I need at all.

I omitted the `all` goal, because the makefile doesn't even work for arbitrary individual files.

I think I am missing some paramount knowledge about how make searches and matches the rules etc. I have practically crisscrossed the manual for nth time now, but it's quite cryptic and I get boo-eyed before I manage to grok it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, the last rule is intended to copy the static assets to the build directory. If so, the first solution that comes to mind, is to turn it into a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). This way, the rule only applies to the targets you specify. You'll have to construct a list of the static assets for this.

```
STATICS := $(addprefix $(DESTDIR), ...)
$(STATICS): $(DESTDIR)%: %
    $(INSTALL_DATA) -D $< $@
```

**Edit in response to the comment:**
I think the following should construct a list of the files you need.

```
STATICS := $(addprefix $(DESTDIR), $(filter-out %.php %.html, $(wildcard *)))
```

Comment: Wow, that sounds promising. Except, how do I specify that my statics are "everything else but *.php and *.html"? I would have to either exclude these patterns explicitly with `$(shell find ! -name \*.php ! -name \*.html)` or maybe I can actually do `$(shell find)` to get me a list of everything, and hope that this rule won't kick in when other rules take precedence?

Comment: @amn: You could construct a "list of everything" (personally, I would use the make intrinsic `wildcard` function instead of a shell invocation), and then use the `filter-out` function to remove the unwanted files. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Fair enough, but as far as my experience with makes own `wildcard` goes, it doesn't descend into subdirectories, does it? I have folders within folders of files, you see.

Comment: @amn: Correct; in that case you'll have to use `find`.